# SQL Server copy contents based on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my DB I have 7 rows for 3 different entities, I want to mirror the contents of one entity to the other two based on an ID value.  I do not know if an update statement is appropriate.

```
CoId  DocumentType  StatusId  StatusDescription  Default  Text  Progression  Environment  RequiredOnAssign  TS  DocumentFilterGroup
```

These are my column headers, `CoId` can have one of three values, 1, 2, or 3. I wish to copy the contents of 1 into 2 and 3 based on status ID. I have having trouble articulating further than this.

Comment: give example please : what data you have and what you need in result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then a self-join is your best friend:

```
UPDATE t1
SET DocumentType = t1.DocumentType, StatusDescription = t1.StatusDescription, Default = t1.Default -- the same for the rest of the fields
FROM table t1 
INNER JOIN table t2 
ON t1.CoID in (2,3) and t2.CoID = 1
WHERE StatusID = ...
```